# Doctrine Memcache::get() generates: Failed reading line from stream (0) Exception

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, memcached

I have a laravel 4/Doctrine 2 application which randomly (20 times/day) generates the following error:

```
Memcache::get(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0)
```

Google and the official documentation didn't reveal anything aside from this question asked years ago: [Memcache error: Failed reading line from stream (0) Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6489236/2853903)

This question doesn't help me much as in my case I'm not maxing out on maximum connection nor on the available cache.

My environment looks as follows:

- PHP 5.5.22
- MySQL 5.5.41
- Laravel 4.0.1
- Doctrine 2

Over the past 5 days this error occurred 126 times, however I can't see any problems in the Memcache stats. They look as follows:

```
STAT uptime 543029
STAT version 1.4.4
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT get_hits 25191524
STAT get_misses 276599
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT evictions 0
```

Comment: As an additional clarification: In my application I let Doctrine to handle the cache, using the `->useResultCache(true,300)` statement. Doctrine is configured to use memcache at `localhost:11211`.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to a different production machine with the exact same software specs solved the problem.

The internal conclusion we reached was that this issue was caused by a hardware issue.